# Is Qt Designer changes its reference for coordination value every time the form's/layout's size changes?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am new into Python GUI programming, I want to know if Qt Designer always change its geometry calculation for x and y values (or top and left values)? Like for example when I export python code to my VSCode, I soon realize that the x and y value for each different project and forms can be different depends on the size of the form/layout. Is there any reference to calculate so I can automatically re-arrange my GUI elements? Thank you

I expect that if I can combine each form/layout into single application I dont need to re-arrange my Python elements

Comment: `so I can automatically re-arrange my GUI elements?` - use [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html)

Comment: There's rarely any real need to make such calculations. This is a very common mistake made by new users. *Do not use absolute sizes and positions to arrange the GUI*. It may seem easier to do things that way to begin with, but it can quickly become very difficult to manage once the GUI starts to become more complex. I would therefore *strongly recommend* that you work through a [tutorial on layouts](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-layout/) so that you get a proper understanding of how [layout management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) works in Qt.

Comment: I see! I used absolute size and position, thank you @ekhumoro I really didnt know about this.

Comment: @Gerald60111 The first result you'd probably get by querying "Qt layout" on most search engines should exactly point to the most important references (including using [layouts in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)), so please consider improving your research efforts for future reference. Also, Qt objects in Python are not "Python elements": PyQt is a *binding*, what you use from Python are just *references* to *wrapped objects* created by the Qt library (which is written in C++). I strongly suggest you to do some research on the topic, as that difference should *not* be ignored.